# Generic diff for complex hierarchical data structure

Tags: scala, scala-collections, shapeless

I have a complex data structure consisting of case classes, maps and sets. I would like to know if there is a *generic* mechanism to calculate a "diff" between two structures.

As a simple example:

```
val s0 = Set(1,2,3)
val s1 = Set(2,3,4)
val diff = diff(s0, s1)
// this should contain the information that 1 has been removed and 4 has
// been added
assert(s1 == diff.patch(s0))
```

A somewhat more complex example:

```
case class User(name: String, roles: Set[String])
val user0 = User("Hans", Set("Developer", "Admin")
val user1 = User("Hans", Set("Admin", "Manager")
val diff = diff(user0, user1)
// this should contain the information that "Developer" has been removed
// and "Manager" has been added to the roles field
```

Note that I am interested in a **generic** solution that works for arbitrary case classes and deep hierarchies. I have a feeling that this should be possible using a typeclass-based approach and either shapeless or some boilerplate. Bonus points for an approach that allows specifying the "diff algorithm" for new collection types.

I have found https://github.com/stacycurl/delta . This seems to be pretty close to what I am looking for. But I don't really understand it.

Comment: @stacycurl's library sounds exactly like what you're looking for ... feel free to come and discuss it on the [shapeless gitter channel](https://gitter.im/milessabin/shapeless).

Answer (score 2):

There is a macro-based library [s_mach.datadiff](https://github.com/S-Mach/s_mach.datadiff). I haven't used it, but the front-page example is generating a diff from an arbitrary case class.

Comment: That looks interesting. I will check it out. However, it seems that you have to define the patch objects for each case class manually.